# OpenLayers documentation for WPSClient and layer.events.on

Tags: openlayers-2, events, wps

I am having trouble finding the following documentation:

- The OpenLayers  wpsclient documentation: e.g.: what are the requirements for the wpsclient JavaScript to run JTS:overlaps or JTS: Difference

  ```
  wpsClient.execute({
  server: 'local',
  process: 'JTS:splitPolygon',   //if this changes to another function
  inputs: {
  polygon: mypolygon,            //what is required here??
  line: myline
  }
  ```
- The documentation for OpenLayers layer.events.on({...*sketchcomplete and more but I don't know what they are and where to find the info*).

What options are there? I can't find this in the OpenLayers API documentation. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here!! so I apologise if that's the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found an answer to the first point. Using a request to geoserver. Turns out "overlaps" requires input of a: and b: not "polygon" like the split tool.

```
    wpsClient.execute({
    server: 'local',
    process: 'JTS:overlaps',   //wps function
    inputs: {
    a: mypolygon,           //inputs
    b: mypolygon            
    }
```

[How to find required parameters](http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/processing/wpsclient/index.html)

For the openlayers documentation on layer events, I found it at [openlayers doc link](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.events)